# Not sure if callback inside d3.json get called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3 select some elements, append `g` and generate an axis inside of svg.

I've debugged each step inside of `renderWeather` and it seems that `d3.json` did get executed but I see no elements rendering. I couldn't figure out why.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as d3 from 'd3'


 export default class Weather extends Component { 

 componentDidMount () {
    this.renderWeather()
 }

 componentDidUpdate () {
    this.renderWeather()
 }

 renderWeather = () => {

  const tmp = (d) => {
  const xScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([1, 10])
  .range([20, 470])

  const yScale = d3
  .scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 40])
  .range([480, 20])

  const xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom()
  .scale(xScale)
  .tickSize(480)
  .ticks(8)

  d3.select(this.refs.container)
  .append('g')
  .attr('id', 'xAxisG')
  .call(xAxis)

  d3.select(this.refs.container)
  .append('rect')
  .style('width', 100)
  .style('height', 100)

// I haven't used any data, just trying to make it work first
}


  // dummy url here
  d3.json('https://google.com', tmp)
}

render() {
 return (
  <svg ref="container">
  </svg>
)
```

}
}

I expect the xAxis in the bottom but could see nothing inside `<svg></svg>` Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The D3.js [D3-fetch module](http://As%20mentioned%20in%20the%20D3-fetch%20[documentation][2],) uses the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#Concepts_and_usage) API to handle HTTP requests.

Therefore, to load and parse the JSON object, you will need to resolve the promise which was returned within the `then()` statement.

```
d3.json('some-path').then(response => {
  console.log(response); 
  // handle the rest here
  tmp(response);
});
```

Likewise, the anonymous function from `tmp`, within the `renderWeather()` method, should be called within the `then()` statement, since the rendering of the chart is dependent on the data returned by `d3.json()`.

Comment: This `d3.json('https://google.com').then(d => tmp(d))` works

Comment: @jen007 ah, yes I just realised you created an anonymous function. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Is there any way of exposing json response `d` as a global variable or this is the only way of accessing `d`?

Comment: You may assign try assigning it to a property within your class! This way, you can access it anywhere else in the class

Comment: `d3.json('https://google.com').then(d => this.data = d)` will have `this.data` available for entire react component. Thanks!!